# Align Edges at 45 Degree Angle

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, 3d-cursor, transform-orientation

How can I align these crease edges at 45 & -45 degree angle?

[image]

Comment: if you use the knife tool and press C you'll be able to cut at 45°

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Align the Vertices of one side to an axis: <kbd>s</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
2. Use the **shear tool** with a value of 1 for 45°